# Grabbing and displaying all files in a server hosted folder

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the following JS code to grab and display certain files from a server hosted folder. How would I go about grabbing all .mp4 files from a folder without having to listed them one by one in variable videoList?

```
<script>
    var videoList = ["assets/vid/wavy.mp4", "assets/vid/tsunami.mp4"];
        videoList.sort(function(a, b) {return 0.5 - Math.random()});

    $("#videoplayer").html("<video id='video' autoplay loop><source src='" + 
    videoList[0] + "' type='video/mp4'></video>");

    var vid = document.getElementById("video");
        vid.volume = 0.20;
</script>
```

Comment: you mean you want JS to discover what files are on the server in that folder without having to know the names in advance? You'd have to make a HTTP request to the server for that folder, and hope it returns some HTML which list the filenames, and parse that. A lot of servers will give you a 403 error though if they don't allow folder contents to be listed. YMMV. This is a task which is more suited to a server-side script which has the correct permissions.

Comment: I do apologise for not articulating the question but I don't think that's what I'm looking to do. I'm simple trying to remove the need of having to type out each and every single .mp4 in the residing folder. I have two of them listed `var videoList = ["assets/vid/wavy.mp4", "assets/vid/tsunami.mp4"];` I have more than 50 of them however so I'm looking for a way to use the entire folder in one line. I know you can use an * for this. Just not sure how to implement it. `var videoList = ["assets/vid/*.mp4"];` ??

Comment: well in that case how would your code know what to insert into the "src" of the video elements? It needs to have the exact filenames. If you aren't going to type them out explicitly, then where will the code get them from? It would have to get a list of the current contents of the folder somehow. The only way to do that from JS is by the method I described, which may or may not work depending on the config of the server. To do what you're describing is potentially possible, but it'll be a lot simpler with a server-side script.

Comment: _“I know you can use an * for this”_ - no, you can not. You can do that when you actually have access to the full listing of file names, so that you can then apply this pattern and decide which ones match and which ones don’t. Of course you can _not_ do that here, because you do _not_ have a full list of all files here. Only the server knows which files are in that directory, so unless your server generates a list and sends it to the client somehow, you can of course not use a wildcard pattern in your client-side code, because you have no data to check against this pattern in the first place.

Comment: "Just not sure how to implement it.". I've described above how you'd have to implement it. Is it not clear? And you can't use a * btw, you just need the folder name. A HTTP URL doesn't understand the *. If you did it server-side though (big hint again!!!) then you maybe could use * to indicate you want all the files in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use the DirectoryListings. Assuming you have access to the server and can configure that the specific directory should show a file listing when accessed through `[...]/folder_name/` [See Apache's DirectoyListings config](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings) to have an idea of what's available.

You could get that through ajax, and parse the HTML to retrieve the files and display them.

If you cannot configure your webserver to serve such page, you'll need to create a server-side script to read the folder content and server that through an ajax call.

As the current state of OP, I am unable to provide you with code that would work as we have no information about your server-side stack.